# Исполнение программы каждый месяц и каждые 3 месяца

Tags: c#, .net

По указке сверху переделываю свои проекты с использованием `C#` и `.NET`. А так же меняются операционные системы с `Posix` подобных на `Windows`. В связи с этим возникают вполне состоятельные вопросы, как реализуется то или иное на другой операционной системе.

К вопросу. Есть некая рутина опроса базы данных и манипуляции с данными по итогу данного опроса. Рутина бухгалтерская и ее необходимо проводить каждый месяц (и еще одна дополнительная каждые 3 месяца, но это не так важно). Каким образом организуется решение данной задачи с использованием `C#` и `.NET`?

Ранее решение запускалось через `cron` и отслеживалось состояние через `python`-скрипт.

В `.NET` нашел такую штуку [Timer.Interval](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=net-6.0). Но по опыту ясно, что данное решение релевантно для коротких интервалов (поправьте если не так). И я хочу найти решение, которое мне не надо будет переделывать через некоторое время, то есть каноническое правильное решение.

Comment: Канонически правильное - планировщик задач в винде(аналог крона)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков похоже на истину, есть ли ограничения связанные с правами доступами к тем или иным ресурсам или просто указать `exe`шник и все права на исполнение перейдут к приложению?

Comment: Если не хочется планировщик, то есть еще библиотека Quartz.NET, ее часто используют на ASP.NET Core серверах в качестве планировщика. Timer как вы уже поняли, не подходит для этой задачи.

Comment: @Dmitry что касается планировщика винды, это больше сисадминский вопрос, и к C# прямого отношения не имеет. Вопросы по нему лучше задавать отдельно. Насколько я помню, запуск запланированной там задачи можно выполнить от имени любого пользователя, доступного в системе. Чтобы это понять, надо попробовать настроить задачу хотя-бы один раз.

Comment: @aepot поскольку еще не так силен в этом + не понятно как это реализовывать, поэтому эти тэги. Поправите?

Comment: Вы сами можете редактировать пост так как нужно. Для начала создайте задачу в планировщие руками, посмотрите как работает, и только потом если потребуется, переходите к програмному управлению задачами планировщика.

Comment: Права доступа - зависят от пользователя под которым задача будет запускаться, Пользователя можно выбрать любого от которого у вас есть пароль, в т.ч. системные учетные записи(для указания таковых нужно быть администратором системы).